# In proof of Bertrand's postulate, $ \forall n \quad \exists p \mid n<p<2n$ why does $\sqrt{2n}<p<2n/3 \implies p\mid\binom{2n}{n}$ exactly once

Tags: number-theory

Background: Bertrand's postulate states that there is at least 1 prime denoted $p$ between every $(n,2n)$. In a proof of this, I think there is an error. This proof is from KENNETH Rosen, Elementary Number Theory, 3.2, problem 24 5th edition. So far the book has been good, but the solutions have some obvious errors that make it look like the solutions were ghost written by an undergrad.

If $2n/3<p\le n$ then $p$ divides $n!$ exactly once and $(2n)!$ exactly twice, so $p\nmid {2n \choose n}$. The proof writer states if $\sqrt{2n}<p<2n/3$ then $p\mid {2n \choose n}$ exactly once. Was this a mistake? Shouldn't it be when $\sqrt[3]{2n}<p\le \sqrt{2n}$?

Comment: Please give the source of the proof to which you are referring. Thanks!

Comment: Please not that it implies $p^2 > 2n$

Comment: Check: $n = 32$, $\sqrt[3]{2n} = 4,\, \sqrt{2n} = 8$. For $p = 5$, we have $p \nmid \binom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: Let me think for a second. The lower bound may be wrong to get the first p divisor in n! to divide only one of p*p in 2n!

Comment: Also, $13 \nmid \binom{64}{32}$. So $\sqrt{2n}$ is also the wrong lower bound. $n/2 < p \leqslant 2n/3$ implies that $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ exactly once. But for $p > \sqrt{2n}$, $p$ divides $\binom{2n}{n}$ _at most once_.

Comment: yes, only then will $p \in 2n!$ three times.

Comment: While this question is resolved, for my own future reference: The total divisions of p in 2n! is $\lfloor 2n/p\rfloor + \lfloor 2n/p^2\rfloor + \dots $